# How to use LazyColumn stickyHeader in combination with Paging in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging

I have implemented `LazyColumn` with [Paging](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#large-datasets), but I'm now trying to add [sticky headers](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#sticky-headers) as well.

The [`stickyHeader()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListScope#stickyHeader(kotlin.Any,kotlin.Function1)) function is not available inside the `items()` scope, so I don't see how this should work.

```
@Composable
fun MovieList(movies: Flow<PagingData<Movie>>) {
    val lazyMovieItems: LazyPagingItems<Movie> = movies.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    LazyColumn {
        // TODO: Add sticky headers
        items(lazyMovieItems) { movie ->
            MovieItem(movie = movie!!)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I add the `stickyHeader`s?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
@Composable
fun MovieList(movies: Flow<PagingData<Movie>>) {
    val lazyMovieItems = movies.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    LazyColumn {
        val itemCount = lazyMovieItems.itemCount
        var lastCharacter: Char? = null

        for (index in 0 until itemCount) {
            // Gets item without notifying Paging of the item access,
            // which would otherwise trigger page loads
            val movie = lazyMovieItems.peek(index)
            val character = movie?.name?.first()

            if (movie !== null && character != lastCharacter) {
                stickyHeader(key = character) {
                    MovieHeader(character)
                }
            }

            item(key = movie?.id) {
                // Gets item, triggering page loads if needed
                val movieItem = lazyMovieItems[index]

                Movie(movieItem)
            }

            lastCharacter = character
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `getAsState` is deprecated in alpha14, now you can directly use the index as lazyMovieItems[index].

Comment: Be careful using this solution: the for loop will every single time the user will fetch new items and, if you have a lot of results (e.g. hundreds of thousands or millions), it will easily run out of memory or degrade the scroll performance (think about iterating over a million items on the UI thread every time you fetch a new page).

Comment: is not using `lazyMovieItems.itemSnapshotList` gives better performance then loop for all elements (`lazyMovieItems.itemCount`)?